# Made a new model in Django. But it's not showing up in the database

Tags: python, django, django-models

I am using Django 1.1.4 with python 2.6. I just added a new model to the list of models and used the syncdb command, but it's not showing in the database. I have already made sure I use 'my_app' name for app label in the Meta class. I also tried making a new database and syncing all the models again, but strangely my model is the only one not getting synced. Below I have included the code:

```
from django.db import models
from coredump.analyzer.models.model import ExtendedModel

class Netpath(ExtendedModel):

 buildno=models.IntegerField()
 path = models.CharField(max_length=300)


 class Meta:
  app_label = 'analyzer'
  ordering = ['buildno']

 def __unicode__(self):
  return '%d' % self.buildno
```

Extended Model is another model that I have made that works perfectly fine with the other models in the framework.Adding it's code as well won't be that useful.
Any help will be greatly appreciated

Comment: ^It actually returns a class object when present.Else it makes it and returns it.It works well and good with the present models

Answer (score 1):

`syncdb` will only create tables for models found in `<app>.models`. Import the model class there if necessary.

Comment: Yes. I am cuurently working on 2 apps: analyzer and job_mgmt.My netpath.py file resides in the analyzer folder.SO, that is not the problem.

Comment: So then you're importing `analyzer.netpath.Netpath` into `analyzer.models` already?

Comment: ^Strangely enough, I changed the folder of netpath from analyzer to job_mgmt(the other app) and it worked. Django works in mysterious ways. Thanks for your help though.

Answer (score 1):

did your new model was on a new apps ? in this case, don't forget to add the new apps in INSTALLED_APPS settings...

in fact, django is absolutely not mysterious or magic.

Comment: ^ Sorry for the wrong jargon of words, but I was not able to find the reason behind it not working in one app and working in the other. Both apps have been included in the INSTALLED_APPS settings. Infact, I am working on an already working code.So, these things weren't the issue.